# rect move dosen't work

Tags: pygame, rect

```
import pygame, random
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((700,500))
ball = pygame.image.load('C://python32/ball.jpg')
brick = pygame.image.load('C://python32/brick.jpg')
rect1 = ball.get_rect()
rect2 = brick.get_rect()
screen.fill((255,255,198))
screen.blit(ball,rect1)
screen.blit(brick,rect2)
pygame.display.flip()
if rect1.colliderect(rect2):
    x=random.randrange(0,550)
    y=random.randrange(0,350)
    rect2.move(x,y)            #<-------This part
    pygame.display.flip()
```

I have 2 images ball and brick. When I load them on pygame the 2 images collide. So the if rect1.colliderect(rect2) should work. I tested that by putting is a print function. But the rect2.move dosen't work it doesn't show the change on the pygame. What is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

[`pygame.Rect.move`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.move) creates a new rect object with the new position which you have to assign to a variable if you want to use it later.

If you just want to modify the existing rect, you can call the [`move_ip`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.move_ip) method (ip stands for in-place), so that the rect is still the same object with a new position.

Comment: Do you have your code in a while loop? If not, you have to blit the images and call `pygame.display.flip()` again after you update the position.
By the way, you shouldn't use absolute paths for your images and you also shouldn't store your files and other resources inside of your Python directory.